# custom attribute changes in .NET 4

Tags: c#, unit-testing, attributes, c#-4.0, custom-attributes

I recently upgraded a C# project from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.  I have a method that extracts all MSTest test methods from a given list of `MethodBase` instances.  Its body looks like this:

```
return null == methods || methods.Count() == 0
    ? null
    : from method in methods
      let testAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(method,
          typeof(TestMethodAttribute))
      where null != testAttribute
      select method;
```

This worked in .NET 3.5, but since upgrading my projects to .NET 4, this code always returns an empty list, even when given a list of methods containing a method that is marked with `[TestMethod]`.  Did something change with custom attributes in .NET 4?

Debugging, I found that the results of `GetCustomAttributesData()` on the test method gives a list of two `CustomAttributeData` which are described in Visual Studio 2010's 'Locals' window as:

1. `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.DeploymentItemAttribute("myDLL.dll")`
2. `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethodAttribute()` -- this is what I'm looking for

When I call `GetType()` on that second `CustomAttributeData` instance, however, I get `{Name = "CustomAttributeData" FullName = "System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData"}    System.Type {System.RuntimeType}`.  How can I get `TestMethodAttribute` out of the `CustomAttributeData`, so that I can extract test methods from a list of `MethodBase`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly mistake on my part:  my test-method-extracting method was in a Class Library project that referenced Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework so that it could look for `TestMethodAttribute` as a custom attribute.  When I upgraded my Solution from VS 2008 to VS 2010, the conversion process automatically updated references from Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=**9.0.0.0** to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=**10.0.0.0** in my test projects.  It did not update the reference in my Class Library project, however, so that was still pointing to the old UnitTestFramework reference.  When I changed that project to point to the 10.0.0.0 library, my code below worked as expected:

```
return null == methods || methods.Count() == 0
    ? null
    : from method in methods
      let testAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(method,
          typeof(TestMethodAttribute))
      where null != testAttribute
      select method;
```

Also, the code [Jon suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951984/custom-attribute-changes-in-net-4/2951996#2951996) worked as well, once I updated the reference.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using

```
method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestMethodAttribute), false)
```

instead? Asking the target for the custom attributes has usually been the way I've gone about fetching them.

Here's a hasty example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class FooAttribute : Attribute {}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var query = typeof(Test).GetMethods()
            .Where(method => method.GetCustomAttributes(
                              typeof(FooAttribute), false).Length != 0);

        foreach (var method in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(method);
        }
    }

    [Foo]
    public static void MethodWithAttribute1() {}

    [Foo]
    public static void MethodWithAttribute2() {}

    public static void MethodWithoutAttribute() {}

}
```

Comment: yes, and I've tried passing `true` so it checks ancestors, too.  I always get back an empty array of `object`s.

Comment: @Sarah: In that case, please post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. I've shown an example which *does* work.

Comment: false alarm!  My project was referencing the old .NET 3.5/VS 2008 version of the UnitTestFramework library.  Switching to the .NET 4/VS 2010 version of UnitTestFramework (10.0.0.0) fixed the problem.

Comment: @Sarah: Ah, right - so the reflection attribute type wasn't the same as the one on the methods...